# Mix sanitized html and raw html in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I have a long list of words, separated by colon (`<word 1>:word 2:word 3:etc`) and I want it to be splitted on the colon, instead of the space character, when resizing the browser.

I found that if you put the character `&#8203` after the colon, it will be splitted the way I want, but to insert this character in a blazor page.

How can I insert this character after the colon, without rendering the words as unsanitized html?

Something like `&lt;word 1&gt;:&#8203word 2:&#8203word 3:etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace using the unicode equivalent of the zero-width space, not the html.

`.Replace(":", ":\u200b")` will render `:&ZeroWidthSpace;`, which is the same as `:&#8203;`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it using regex by doing this:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"[:]", m => string.Format(@"{0}&#8203", m.Value));
```

Basically this part:

```
{0}&#8203
```

Means that on the occurrence of the captured string, we just add the character you want (in this case &#8203)

Here's a fully working sample:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var myString = "word 1:word 2:word 3:etc";
        var formattedString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"[:]", m => string.Format(@"{0}&#8203", m.Value));
        Console.WriteLine(formattedString);
    }
}
```